# Printing perl struct members

Tags: perl

I have a struct and would like to print out the contents within quotes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Class::Struct;

struct( astruct => [ test => '$']);

my $blah = new astruct;
$blah->test("asdf");

print "prints array reference: '$blah->test'\n";
print "prints content: '", $blah->test, "'\n";
```

The output is

```
prints array reference: 'astruct=ARRAY(0x20033af0)->test'
prints content: 'asdf'
```

Is there a way to print the contents within the quotes?

Its making my code a bit scruffy having to open and close quotes all the time.  It's also problematic when using `` to run commands which use the contents of structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$blah` holds an array reference and is *interpolated* into the string before it can be *dereferenced*. To change that, we put the dereferencing either outside the String:

```
print "prints no array reference any more: '".($blah->test)."'\n";
# parenthesis was optional
```

or pull a little trick with an anonymous array:

```
print "prints no array reference any more: '@{[$blah->test]}'\n";
```

We dereference (`@{...}`) an anonymous array (`[...]`) which we construct from the return value of the `test` method. (Our your struct field, whatever.)

While both these methods work when constructing a string, the second form can easily be used in a `qx` or *backticks* environment. You could also build a string `$command` and then execute that with `qx($command)`.

If you don't need the additional functionality of the `Class::Struct`, you can always use hashes and spare yourself the hassle:

```
%blah = (test => 'asdf');
print "prints my value: '$blah{test}'\n";
```

or

```
$blah = {test => 'asdf'};
print "prints my value: '$blah->{test}'\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Perls' [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) ?

> Given a list of scalars or reference variables, writes out their
>   contents in perl syntax. The references can also be objects. The
>   content of each variable is output in a single Perl statement. Handles
>   self-referential structures correctly.

Comment: That could make printing strings easier but wouldnt solve the `` problem.  I guess reallu I was hoping for a way to kind of derefence it in place.